# database connection via. php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have an website containing a survey inside an html form.

At the end of the survey there's a submit type button that "calls" a .php file where the data is inserted into a database. That all works nicely, but what I need to do is to have another php file called after the first page of the survey has been filled out to check if there already exists a tuple in the database with that information.

But seeing as I already have a submit type button in the end I can't use that right? 
So how do I workaround this? any ideas?

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate and possibly show what you've tried so far? It's hard to provide a solution to something you have little information about.

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking before the start of the survey, so the user doesn't have to fill it in twice?

Comment: ok check comments to answer below where I've tried to elaborate :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide some code that you have tried..

You can use [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
    // record exists
    // show some error and don't save
    }
    else
    {
    //no record exists
    // save in db
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can look if the tings alreddy exist in the database befor you put it there.. you can do that with simple php

```
$name = $_POST['name']; // save the name from the form to the var.
$last_name = $_POST['lastname']; // save the last name from the form to the var.
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `name` = '".$name."' AND `last_name` = '".$last_name."' "); // look in the database if there is alreddy a record with that name.
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){ // if its bigger than 0 it exists
  // give an error back to the user that they alreddy exist
}
else{ // if not exists
  // user your code that puts it to the database
}
```

Comment: The first page is the "start" so to speak where user fills out his own information.

I already have the .php file that pulls out alle the relevant information from the tuples in the database what I need to do is find a way to "call" this file when the user tries to proceed with a  next button for instance.

Comment: like with a submit button that has an action"submit.php" that calls the php file for submitting his data in the end I also have a check.php that I would like to call.

Comment: I first tried doing the onclick javascript for html input types and call the .php file inside the javascript method but of course that didn't work since javascript is clientside and php serverside. The n I was thinking about ajax but seeing as it is not necessary to use that kind of performance that seemed like overkill if there was an easier way? I was thinking if a regular html "input" type button had some sort of action like the submit type of the form?

Comment: You can also use jQuery's plugin [jQuery.validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate the fields its even more user friendly than call a new page.. with the plugin the users sees what he did wrong when he fillend in or press next.